# Operator !! in Kernel C

Tags: c, kernel

I encountered the below code in C program.

```
int a = !! b ;
```

variable b is also an integer.
Initially I thought it is 'not' operator with a typo :)

Can someone help in explaining this?

Comment: Linux kernel programmers are too "special" to write `b != 0`, is all.

Answer (score 4):

This is operator `!`, which is used twice in row. If `b` is non-zero, `a` gets value 1, and if `b` is zero, `a` gets value 0.